# \printbibliography fails output

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, xetex

I am trying to get running the example of [Sharelatex](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX). Though the output PDF I `\printbibliography` just won't do its job. I do get 3 errors as well, but I am unable to figure out how to solve this problem.

I use Ubuntu 15.10 amd64, TeXstudio 2.9.4, Texlive 1.2 (texliveonfly --version), XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (xetex --version), BibTeX 0.99d (bibtex --version).

My files are `text.tex` and `sample.bib` and are listed below, as is my `expected output` and my `real output`.

How would I get the bibliography running?

**text.tex**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
    Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's
    book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**sample.bib**:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = "1973",
    chapter = "1.2",
    keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

**expected output**:

[image]

**real output**:

[image]

EDIT 1:

If I run bibtex directly through TexStudio, I get the following error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Are you compiling this on your own machine? You need to compile it with `latex`, then `biber` (or `bibtex`), and then `latex` again.

Comment: With your set-up (specifically `\usepackage{biblatex}`) you need to run Biber and not BibTeX. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: @moewe Already tried to use biber, but same result. I created `EDIT 1` and posted the error when creating the bibliography. As everything _should_ work fine, I assume that there is some software I still have to install in my Ubuntu 15.10 system. I tried out just to install everything Ubuntu has to offer in Texlive (basically `sudo apt-get install texlive*`), but this didn't change the outcome.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of TeXLive Ubuntu 15.10 ships. The error message suggests though that you are running BibTeX and not Biber.

Comment: Alright, I got it now. Had to install biber with `sudo apt-get install biber` as it wasn't on the system. Now everything works well as expected. Bibtex still doesn't work, but it's alright as long as there is another solution for it. Biber will do. Thanks a lot for the help! Very appreciated!

Comment: BibTeX does not work in your example because the default value for the `backend` option is `backend=biber` (you can see that in the `.log` file). If you want to use BibTeX you need to ask for it specifically with `backend=bibtex`. (In order to be able to compile everything, you probably need to delete the temporary files after this change.) But since Biber offers superior features, working with Biber is the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't have all the required packages for biblatex to run. You need to

1. Install `texlive-bibtex-extra`, `texlive-latex-extra` and `biber` packages for ubuntu by opening a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, then entering the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-latex-extra biber
   ```
2. Hit `enter` and yes to installation questions
3. To avoid getting warning messages you should specify biber as the backend for biblatex in your `.tex` file with `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. So your file `sample.bib` can be left the same as what you posted, but your `test.tex` file should look like:

**test.tex**

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{sample.bib}

    \begin{document}
        Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

4. Before compiling, make sure that BibLaTeX is selected by going to the `Bibliography` menu, then at the bottom there should be `Type:BibTeX` or `Type:BibLaTeX`, make sure it is `BibLaTeX`
5. Finally, select `options` menu, then `configure TeXstudio` then on the left, click on `Build` and make sure `Default Bibliography Tool` is set to `Biber` as in the below screenshot:

[image: TeXstudio Build settings for Biblatex]

Comment: With a recent version of `biblatex` one doesn't need to specify `backend=biber` to get Biber as back-end, it is the standard (you will get a warning, though).

Answer (score 1):

You need to: 
 - Compile with pdflatex or xelatex
 - Run bibtex or biber
 - Recompile with pdflatex or xelatex.

Your code works fine for me when these instructions are followed.

Comment: I tried out latex, pdflatex, xelatex, and lualatex. All have the same outcome. When running bibtex directly, I get an error. I posted it above in `EDIT 1`.